# Set margin between col-md-* div classes without harming responsiveness of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to generate html code automatically getting input as list of html controls with set of properties such as x,y,value etc (getting those values from hand made sketch of the html page). I have used bootstrap row classes and col-md-* classes for each control by using set of algorithms. Therefore I have added margin-left style for each col-md-* div based on x value of control. Then I could not get responsibility of the page when it is varying screen size. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: I found way to do this. With the help of below way, we can set margin.                                                                             <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">.col-md-4 .col-md-offset-4</div>

Answer (score 0):

Don't use margin. Use padding.

Also if all fails, just add an inner container.